# iOS Swift - alert dialog with pages

Tags: ios, swift, alert

I want to provide my users an Info-Dialog, where they can click through several parts of information to show them the flow of the application.

How can I implement a UIAlertController that has several pages and where I can move to the next or previous via a button click?

Comment: You need to create your own custom class (UIVIewCotnroller) to do that. Alert controller does not provide that functionality

Comment: try to find solution for _onboarding_ flow / screen on iOS, I think you might find brilliant ideas for your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create custom `UIViewController`. But if you'd like to make it feel like an `UIAlertController`you can use [AlertOnboarding library](https://github.com/PhilippeBoisney/AlertOnboarding) as a [pod](https://cocoapods.org/pods/AlertOnboarding).

And [here](https://github.com/vsouza/awesome-ios#walkthrough--intro--tutorial) you can find a bunch of walkthrough/onboarding/tutorial libraries for iOS.